# Kotlin - Use Realm Module in android

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I have an android app with Realm and some Realm Module that help me to isolate synced Realm and i decide to migrate from Java to Kotlin.

```
@RealmModule(classes = arrayOf(Category::class, Product::class))
private class ShopModule
fun getShop(user: SyncUser, path: String): RealmConfiguration {
    return SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, path)
            .modules(ShopModule())
            .build()
}
```

function getShop return RealmConfiguration to use in Realm.getInstance().
 After some converting show me some error when build() has occurred:

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.ShopModuleMediator
```

please help me to continue my migration. I can't understand what's wrong because this method works for me in java.
**UPDATE:**
After good Q&A in comments and so many change and try in my project i found when using kotlin in my project ShopModuleMediator was not generated and when convert app project from Java to Kotlin project has worked befor clean Project.

Comment: What is the order of applied Gradle plugins? What language is `Category` and `Product` written in? What are your Gradle dependencies, are there any marked as `annotationProcessor`?

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce, `Category` and `Product` are written in Kotlin. I use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3` and don't use any `annotationProcessor`

Comment: I wasn't kidding that I need your order of plugins `apply plugin: 'blah'`. SPecifically if you apply `kotlin-kapt` and `realm-android` in the right order

Comment: sorry @EpicPandaForce i use `com.android.feature`, `kotlin-android`, `kotlin-kapt`, `kotlin-android-extensions` in current feature and `realm-android` in base feature

Comment: Feature? Is this app an instant app?

Comment: both of them app and instant app

Comment: i use `kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}` but error yet show

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all, Realm doesn't support feature plugin yet AFAIK https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4820 :o

Comment: this error not rely on feature plugin because i recreate my project without instant app but this error has shown. it's seem to problem is in kotlin and realm module. if you like to resolve this problem please vote up question to get answer erlier

Comment: Does ShopModule have `library=true` set?

Comment: I test so many structure but not working. I create external library and same module with `library = true` but same error has occurred, i do so many clean, rebuild, and delete build folders every time... oops

Comment: I'd have to see the project at this point to make any educated guesses, but that probably won't happen so you might be able to ask for help at help[at]realm.io as well, it helps if you have send a sample project that reproduces the issue

Comment: I made a project to test this, but it cannot be reproduced on my side. @Saeed if you still have this issue, would you please make a sample project and share it somewhere?

Comment: Hi @beeender, i will provide a sample project and share that. thanks for your attention

Comment: with new release of Realm java problem has been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulation with release Realm Java 4.1.0 this problem has been resolved and i share [my test project](https://github.com/c2c2/RealmKotlinShop) you can see result but an important note that for using in instant app you [must use https network and can't use http in instant app](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/policy.html#network_traffic) and i share [another app](https://github.com/c2c2/RealmKotlinShopInstant) that work when run in app mode but when run in instantapp has occurred an error : not permitted by network security policy this is because using http in authentication url.